# WPF Client-Server adding user to queue does not reach a method

Tags: c#, client-server, queue

I'm using a client-server implementation with processerqueues.
But I'm having a problem when a user has to be added to a queue, the method to add is not reachable.

This is the class ManagerServiceClient

```
public class ManagerServiceClient: IManageServiceClient
{
    IDashboardData dashboardData;
    IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public ManagerServiceClient(IDashboardData dashboardData, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.dashboardData = dashboardData;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

    }
    public void ProcessUserList(User[] users)
    {
        dashboardData.Users.Clear();
        users.ToList().ForEach(u => dashboardData.Users.Add(u));
    }


    public void NewQueueItem(Queues.Common.QueueItem item)
    {
        if (item.Action == Queues.Common.QueueActions.Server_ClientConnected)
        {
            if (dashboardData.Users.Where(u => u.Name == (item.Data as string)).Count() == 0)
            {
                if (dashboardData.MainObject == null)
                {
                    dashboardData.AddUser(new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = (item.Data as string) });
                }
                else
                {
                    dashboardData.MainObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            dashboardData.AddUser(new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = (item.Data as string) });
                        }));
                }
            }
        }
```

And the class ManagerServiceServer:

```
class ManageServiceServer : ScsService, IManageServiceServer
{
    ProcessorQueue waitingQueue;
    private readonly ThreadSafeSortedList<long, ServiceClient> clients;

    public ManageServiceServer()
    {
        clients = new ThreadSafeSortedList<long, ServiceClient>();

        waitingQueue = new ProcessorQueue(100);
        waitingQueue.AddProcessor(QueueActions.Manager_RequestUsers, ProcessRequestUsers);
        waitingQueue.Start();
    }

    private void ProcessRequestUsers(object sender, QueueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ClientId != null)
        {
            SendUserListToClient((long)e.Item.ClientId);
        }
    }

    public void SendUserListToClient(long clientId)
    {
        ServiceClient client = clients[clientId];
        List<User> userlist = new List<User>();
        client.ClientProxy.ProcessUserList(userlist.ToArray<User>());
    }

    public void Login(User userInfo)
    {
        if (clients.GetAllItems().Where(x => x.User.Id == userInfo.Id).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException(String.Format("{0}: {1} already logged in.", userInfo.Id, userInfo.Name));

        //Get a reference to the current client that is calling this method
        var client = CurrentClient;

        //Get a proxy object to call methods of client when needed
        var clientProxy = client.GetClientProxy<IManageServiceClient>();

        //Create a ChatClient and store it in a collection
        var chatClient = new ServiceClient(client, clientProxy, userInfo);
        clients[client.ClientId] = chatClient;

        //Register to Disconnected event to know when user connection is closed
        client.Disconnected += Client_Disconnected;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1} logged in.", userInfo.Id, userInfo.Name));

        waitingQueue.Add(new QueueItem() { Action = QueueActions.Manager_RequestUsers, ClientId = client.ClientId, Data = "" });
    }

    #region Private Methods
    /// Handles Disconnected event of all clients.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Client object that is disconnected</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments (not used in this event)</param>
    private void Client_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get client object
        var client = (IScsServiceClient)sender;

        //Perform logout (so, if client did not call Logout method before close,
        //we do logout automatically.
        ClientLogout(client.ClientId);
    }
    /// connection fails.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientId">Unique Id of client that is logged out</param>
    private void ClientLogout(long clientId)
    {
        //Get client from client list, if not in list do not continue
        var client = clients[clientId];
        if (client == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Remove client from online clients list
        clients.Remove(client.Client.ClientId);

        //Unregister to Disconnected event (not needed really)
        client.Client.Disconnected -= Client_Disconnected;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1} logged out.", client.User.Id, client.User.Name));
    }
    #endregion

    public void NewQueueItem(QueueItem item)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var client in clients.GetAllItems())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.ClientProxy.NewQueueItem(item);            
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        );
    }
```

Every client will be added to the queue, but the method NewQueueItem in the managerserviceclient class is never reached. Whats wrong here?

Greets

Solved! I was using 3 seperate projects who had need to be started, but 1 project had to be started without debugging, so then the code in my other project was reachable..

Comment: If you're saying that this line `client.ClientProxy.NewQueueItem(item);` never gets called, then it *could* be because `clients.GetAllItems()` does not return anything?

Comment: it returns the client, but the method NewQueueItem in ManagerServiceClient is never executed, cant debug inside it

Comment: Does it *actually* return anything? Have you debugged the `NewQueueItem` method in the `ManageServiceServer` class?

Comment: When I debug it,the clients are correct, but the NewQueueItem method does not really do something, nothing changed or returns something. It should execute the NewQueueItem method in ManageServiceClient class, but so It doesn't do that.

Comment: Try removing the `Task` and seeing if it will work then? Are you saying that if you put a breakpoint on the first `if` condition inside the `NewQueueItem` method in the `ManagerServiceClient`,  that breakpoint never gets hit?

Comment: removing the task does not work. Yes thats what meant, the breakpoint never gets hit, it says: No executable code is associated with this line